# get amount of messages from qpid on python

Tags: python, message-queue, amqp, qpid

How can I receive amount of messages stored in the queue using **qpid library** on **python**?

I have tried like this:

```
from qpid.messaging import *

broker_rcv = connect_address 
address_rcv = queue_name  + "; { node: { type: queue }, assert: never , create: never, mode: " + "browse" + " }"
connection_rcv = Connection(broker_rcv)
connection_rcv.open()
session_rcv = connection_rcv.session()
receiver = session_rcv.receiver(address_rcv)
print receiver.available()
```

And it always return me 0 messages.

Answer (score 1):

I have soloved this by adding `receiver.capacity = 250`. But if I have more messages in the queue and call `receiver.available()` I recive 250. But it's not a big problem now.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same problem . But my last goal was that to stop and resume messages in queue. I found this:

```
qpidd --default-flow-stop-threshold=90 --default-flow-resume-threshold=75
```

or check this link: https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-cpp-0.34/cpp-broker/book/producer-flow-control.html

This may help you.